# One Class/Multiple Constructors vs. Multiple Classes (Inheritance)

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to implement the following tree-like structure at the moment (i.e., Man, Woman, Child, SpecialMan, SpecialWoman, SpecialChild). Is there a neater/alternate (less repeating code) way I could approach it?

```
public class Person {
    int hat;
    int one_glove;
}

public class Man extends Person {
    int coat;
    int shorts;
}

public class Woman extends Person {
    int coat;
}

public class Child extends Person {
    int shorts;
}
public class SpecialMan extends Man {
    int second_glove;
}

public class SpecialWoman extends Woman {
    int second_glove;
}

public class SpecialChild extends Child {
    int second_glove;
}
```

What I'm thinking is just having the class Person contain all the variables and then simply having multiple constructors for it -> linked to each specific object type?

```
public class Person{
 int hat;
 int one_glove;
 int coat;
 int shorts;
 int second_glove;

 public Person(int coat;int shorts; int hat; int one_glove;){} //Man
 public Person(int coat;int hat; int one_glove;){} //Woman
 public Person(int coat;int shorts; int hat; int one_glove; int second_glove;) {} //SpecialMan

 etc...
}
```

Comment: what is `man` in a constructor?

Comment: Better to use interfaces to indicate the presence of additional fields

Comment: What do you mean One Class/multiple constructors? I my understanding is that a class having more than 1 constructor. You can atleast clarify what is needed and also provide a sample if possible. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach makes sense and follows best practices by only keeping variables (and presumably behavior) that's relevant to each class in the relevant class. By putting them all in the same class, you end up in a situation where an object would have access to a variable it has no need of. Furthermore, in your proposed solution, you would probably end up with a lot of extra code to figure out what 'type' of person it is. eg.

```
if (coat != 0 && shorts == 0) {
  // Do Child stuff
}
```

You could assign each `Person` a 'type' upon when they are instantiated (perhaps using an Enum), but you'd still need to do a check against this where their behaviors diverge. The advantage of your current approach is that class specific behavior is confined to the class it is specific to, so you never have to make this check. If a `Child` has a `play()` method, you'll never need to check whether or not you are actually a child before running it.

So while you may see repeated code in your current approach, it would likely be much clearer than your proposed solution. You could further increase the clarity of your code by careful use of [Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Answer (score 0):

Simply inherit person class and use super

```
> public class Person{
 int hat;
 int one_glove;
 int coat;
 int shorts;
 int second_glove;

public person(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e){
hat  = a;
one_glove = b;
coat = c;
shorts = d;
second_glove = e;
}

}

class man extends person(){

man(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e){
super(a,b,c,d,e);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider simpler example with methods now:

```
public class Animal{
    String name;

    void sleep() {

    }
}

public class Bird extends Animal {
    void whistle() {

    }
}
```

How can you now make only Bird whistle without making all Animals whistle without inheritance.

So if you consider to have methods then surely you want to use inheritance